# How do I allocate probabilities to appropriate events?

Tags: probability

**Que** for detecting a disease, a test gives correct diagnosis with probability $0.99$. It is known that $1\%$ of a population suffers from the disease. If a randomly selected individual from this population tests positive, then the probability that the selected individual actually has the disease is?

I assume (what's wrong, I know it's wrong)
**A** be the event that the test is positive
**B** be the event that the individual is diseased 
Then a/c to question $P(B)=0.01\ P(A\cap B)=0.99$ and I need to find $P(B|A)=$probability that the individual is actually diseased if it's test is positive. If I am not wrong then I am not able to find the required probability with these values.

Comment: To be clear:  are you assuming that the probability of a false positive equals the probability of a false negative ($=.01$)?   That is not equivalent to what you write, but I expect it is what you intend.

Comment: Do you really mean correct diagnosis? Or do you mean that if the person has the disease, then with probability $0.99$ she tests positive, and if the person does not have the disease, then with probability $0.99$ she tests negative?

Comment: The odds of having a disease for a general member are 1:99. The odds the test being correct are 99:1. So the odds of having a disease after a positive test are 1:1 - probability $\frac 1 2$

Comment: What? What is that? @A.S. I do not get your approach.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas I was really thinking this, if the probability of test being accurate is .99 then it means that if she had disease then she is test positive with .99 probability, and that's what I used, what do you mean to say? Please explain.

Comment: $$\frac {P(D|P)}{P(D^c|P)}=\frac {P(D)}{P(D^c)}\frac {P(P|D)}{P(P|D^c)}$$. The second term is the likelihood ratio - not the odds I called it initially, but because $P(P|D^c)=P(N|D)$ they are the same.

Comment: @lulu am I wrong in taking the probability of person having disease=0.01?

Comment: @Abomm, no that's fine.  Let's assume that false positives and false negatives both have probability $.01$.  To model the situation, imagine we had $10,000$ people.  Then, by assumption, there are $100$ people with the disease and $9,900$ without it.  We test everybody.  Then, by assumption,  $.01*9,900=99$ healthy people test positive, while $.99*100=99$ sick people test positive.  Thus the answer is $\frac 12$.

Comment: For real-world medical tests, the probability of a false negative and the probability of a false positive are generally different.  The wording of the questioh is unfortunately unclear, but it is likely that you are expected to assume they are both $0.01$.

Comment: How? it is correctly given that the percentage of diseased person is 1. Why we even consider them as false positive or false negative, this is the number of persons which are diseased just that.No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S^+$ denote that the test shows positive, $S$ the is accurate, $\bar S$ the test was inaccurate and $T$ person has the disease, $\bar T$ does not have the disease. Then the probability of interest is
\begin{align*}
P(T|S^+) &= \frac{P(TS^+)}{P(S^+)}\\
&=\frac{P(S|T)P(T)}{P(ST)+P(\bar S \bar T)}\\
&=\frac{P(S|T)P(T)}{P(S|T)P(T)+P(\bar S|\bar T)P(\bar T)}\\
&=\frac{(.99)(.01)}{(.99)(.01)+(.01)(.99)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I feel like dumb now.

Comment: @Abomm Don't feel that way. Do you need more clarification?

Comment: So the events I explained were correct?

Comment: No thanks you mention it very clearly but I was feeling low because I could not think of using complement events by myself.

Comment: @Abomm Not quite, I changed my answer a little. Now it makes more sense/is more accurate, I think. Do you still follow?

Comment: If we go with this  perspective then how we can say that $P(TS^{+})=P(S|T)P(T)$ I mean how we can know that the positive test we get is accurate

Comment: @Abomm If the person **does** have the disease, and if the test **is** accurate, then the test will show positive.

Comment: As we are taking the case of having disease so the positive test is considered as accurate test OK I get it.

Comment: @Abomm Yes, if the person has a disease, and the test is accurate then the test will show postive.

Comment: Just one thing shouldn't you use $P(S\overline{T})$ instead of $P(\overline{S}\overline{T})$

Comment: @Abomm No, if the person does not have the disease, then an _inaccurate_ test result will show positive.

Comment: @Abomm Remember, in the denominator we are look for all the ways the test will _show_ postive. Hence the $S^+$ notation.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your insight and giving so much of your time. thanks

Comment: @Abomm No problem. Good luck.